# Why my flag on a question was declined with answer-related reason?

Tags: support, flagging

OP asked for migration to SO in comment. I flagged for moderator's attention, and I've got this:

[image: Screenshot]

OK, moderator decided to decline this, and it was his call. But I have no clue why that reason given. It simply does not make sense to me. I didn't use flag to indicate technical inaccuracy. Quite the opposite, if anything. So why this reason?

Comment: What question was that?

Comment: @MPD http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/116397/16495

Comment: Do anyone know if this particular message is "hand-typed" by the mod, under is just canned verbiage the system provides as the default reason whenever a mod declines a flag and don't bother typing in a custom reason?

Comment: It's one of the standard responses.

Answer (score 1):

The declination doesn't have any meaning when applied to a question; it is specific for answers that are flagged as not answers. I would have chosen the one saying that a moderator reviewed the post and didn't find anything wrong.

I guess the moderator got confused from the flag talking of an answer. It happens to us too. `;-)`